# Trouble with pseudo selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover

I need select one by one `<a></a>` and change color with :hover effect

```
<nav class="navbar2 navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Follow:</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></i></a></li>

            </ul> 

      </div>
</nav>

.navbar2 .navbar-nav > li > a:nth-of-type:hover(3) {
  color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the third one shall hover in red?! So?

```
navbar2 .navbar-nav > li:nth-of-type(3) > 
    a:hover {
     color:red;
}
```

Comment: yes ... but this not work for me ...aaa its crazy these selectors

Comment: should work fine though: http://jsfiddle.net/Lduaqmra/ The third item (twitter icon) gets red on hover now.